# "Could not list Contents" error when building in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build

After deleting menu1.xml file I receive this error. This file was never used, and I can not figure out why should I get this error after deleting it. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Please post actual error messages as text instead of screenshots. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try clean project or rebuild project.